# Math library and arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, vectorization

I am to use the Math Library to do some calculations on an array.
I tried something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import math
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
a1 = np.vectorize(a)
print("sin(a) = \n", math.sin(a1))
```

Unfortunately it does not work. An error occur: `"TypeError: must be real number, not vectorize"`.

How can I use the vectorize function to be able to calculate that kind of things?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. As far as I can tell, `vectorize` expects you to pass a function, but you passed an array. And `math.sin` of course expects you to pass a number, but you've passed a `vectorized` (essentially a function). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Read the docs of numpy again, carefully! You probably just want ```np.sin(a)``` (no need to import math; no need to mix these, and especially no need to use vectorize).

Comment: @smarx I would like to get something like this: np.sin(a) but I am to use the math library

Comment: And why do you need to use math?

Comment: The canonical way if `np.sin` is to be avoided is to define `f=np.vectorize(math.sin)` and apply `f(a)`.

Comment: Sounds like a crap assignment

Answer (score 7):

The whole point of [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/) is that you don't need any `math` method or any list comprehension:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> a + 1
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.sin(a)
array([ 0.        ,  0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001])
>>> a ** 2
array([0, 1, 4, 9])
>>> np.exp(a)
array([  1.        ,   2.71828183,   7.3890561 ,  20.08553692])
```

You can use `a` as if it were a scalar and you get the corresponding array.

If you really need to use `math.sin` (hint: you don't), you can [vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) it (the function itself, not the array):

```
>>> vsin = np.vectorize(math.sin)
>>> vsin(a)
array([ 0.        ,  0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import math
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
print("sin(a) = \n", [math.sin(x) for x in a])
```

math.sin requires one real number at a time.