# Whats the difference between np.vectorize() and regular notation

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am new at python and numpy. Consider that I have a function called addTwo  that just returns the given value + 2. My question is what's the difference between np.vectorize(addTwo )(matrix) and addTwo (matrix). both give me the same output.
Basically my question is: if I have following code:

```
import numpy as np
def addTwo(a):
    return a + 2

matr = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
```

I wonder difference between these two:

```
addTwo(matr)
np.vectorize(addTwo)(matr)
```

Comment: add your example to the post please

Comment: Stay away from `vectorize` for now.  Beginners often misuse it, thinking it's a short cut to real 'vectorize'.  The docs are long but should be read in full.

Comment: A recent question about this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46593021 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/44746576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation (
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):
`The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.`
It means there is no reazon in `vectorize` of function wich could be applied directly as it is in your example.
Actually this could lead to degraded performance.
Main goal of the "vectorize" is to hide a for loop from you code. But it will not avoid it neither change expected results.

Comment: @HectorBarbossa No, do not use vectorize. It is much slower in this case.