# Fastest way to do tan() and arctan() on large arrays with GPU in Python?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, trigonometry, numba

This is essentially an expansion of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205757/how-can-i-use-trigonometric-functions-on-gpu-with-numba). The answer provided there says to use the math library for trig functions. Unfortunately, the math library [only works on scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593021/math-library-and-arrays-in-python), not arrays. When I try using njit with np.tan() and np.arctan(), it uses my CPU, not my GPU:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def f1(a):
    np.tan(a)
    return np.arctan(a)
```

I have large arrays (3mil cols) that I need to do both tan() and arctan() on. I have 80 million rows of data to process, but I can batch a few a time to fit it in memory and I can divide these 80mil up into multiple CPU/GPU jobs to help parallelize it. I'd like to use my GPU for all these trig functions if it's faster. Will Numba work for this? Will something like PyTorch work here or does that have too much overhead? What's the fastest way to do trig functions on large arrays?

EDIT: These 3mil column arrays that make up each row are generated dynamically at runtime. I can batch up to ~20 of these at a time without running out of memory, before sending the whole (20,3mil) array for the 2 trig functions and saving the results (thus freeing up memory for the next batch of 20). So I'm just looking for the fastest way to do tan() and arctan() on a (20,3mil) array, and I'll loop through my data 20 rows at a time. CPU or GPU for this? Numba or PyTorch? @njit or @vectorize?

Comment: If the array do not fit in memory, then using a GPU is certainly not useful : the RAM and the disk will be the limiting factor. Using a GPU will make things even slower due to the data transfers (using the quite slow PCI/NvLink interconnect). Besides your Numba function is not a GPU function. I advise to perform an in-place computation and use a fast math library like the one of Intel. Note that single precision numbers are faster to compute. You can also use approximations (AFAIK, CUDA does that). If you use a HDD, all these optimizations are pointless as well as using a GPU and even threads.

Comment: By the way, you can just use a loop to compute array using scalar functions...

Comment: 80M*3M float values will reach up to 1 petabyte. How do you store or generate such huge data? As @JérômeRichard pointed out, it could be much slower than the tan/atan computations. Also, can you use approximations? If so, how accurate do you need it to be?

Comment: @ken Edited my question, I generate each 3mil column of data dynamically at runtime. I can batch about 20 of these rows at once before running out of memory. Looking for the fastest way to do tan() and arctan() on arrays of size ~(20,3mil) and just loop through the 80mil rows 20 at a time. I can split the 80mil rows up among any reasonable number of separate GPU jobs to help parallel it a bit. But my main question is CPU vs GPU and how to implement that solution.

Comment: It may be that Python is the wrong choice for you.  If you fall back to C++, you can use the Intel Performance Primitives, which use SIMD to compute `tan` and `atan`.

Comment: @ken Also, I believe I need good accuracy as this data processes angles over very large distances. However I'd be interested in comparing some precise results to shortcuts if it speeds things up enough and measure how significantly accuracy falls.

Comment: @TimRoberts Where can I find sample code for this? Could cython work for this?

Comment: With the caveat that I've never done it, there is a module:  https://github.com/strawlab/cython_ipp .  I've used IPP extensively from C++, but never from Python.  And just as a side note, arctan is an ugly beast that doesn't behave uniformly over its range.  We had a telemetry system that used arctan in doing quadrature demodulation, and artctan ended up using fully 33% of our CPU time.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In your situation, the fastest way is to do the row generation and the tan/atan calculation in parallel. If the calculation is faster than the generation, the computation time is practically zero, so we need to consider this strategy first. To determine if this strategy is possible, we need to know how long the generation takes and how much CPU resources are available during the generation.

Comment: Also, could you be more specific about `f1`: Which one do you want to calculate, `(tan(a), atan(a))` or `atan(tan(a))`? Is the dtype of `a` float32 or float64? What is the value range of `a`? Any? `[0, 2pi)`? `[-pi/2, pi/2]`?

Comment: @ken No, thank YOU for taking the time to help a stranger. I looked a bit closer at the code today and apparently I only really need to do arctan() on the (batch_size,3mil) array. There is a tan() that comes later but it's on a smaller array with only 360 cols, so (batch_size, 360). I don't mind doing that one on CPU. The range of values for the arctan() is (-pi/2,pi/2) non-inclusive, with most values being very close to 0. They are float64 and I require float64 precision for this, I can't use float32 or lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to show you several implementations.
There is code at the end of this post for benchmarking,
so please try for yourself and find out which one works best for you.

This is the basic implementation that uses numba jit.

```py
import math
import numba as nb
import numpy as np


@nb.njit("float64[:](float64[:])", parallel=True)
def numba_jit_cpu(a):
    out = np.empty_like(a)
    for i in nb.prange(a.shape[0]):
        out[i] = math.atan(a[i])
    return out
```

Regarding your first question, the key is to use the math module, not numpy.

Here is the benchmark result for 20*3 million elements.

```
numba_jit_cpu: 121 ms
```

There are 4 million batches, so it will take about 5.6 days in total.

However, in fact, more than half of this time is spent allocating `out`, which is where the output is stored.
So we could make the function take `out` as an argument and write to it, like many numpy APIs do.

```py
@nb.njit("void(float64[:],float64[:])", parallel=True)
def numba_jit_cpu_buf(a, out):
    for i in nb.prange(a.shape[0]):
        out[i] = math.atan(a[i])
```

```
numba_jit_cpu_buf: 51 ms
```

Now it will take about 2.4 days in total.
This is the fastest way I can currently offer.

As a comparison, let's compare the time it takes to allocate and write to the same size of memory.

```py
def single_thread_allocation(a):
    return np.ones_like(a)


def single_thread_write(a, x):
    x[:] = a
```

```
single_thread_allocation: 87 ms
single_thread_write: 27 ms
```

As you can see, `numba_jit_cpu_buf` is faster than allocating and only about 2 times slower than writing.
If you want a faster way than this, you have to optimize every memory allocation and write.
This level of optimization is required.

But since I am already tried anyway, here are some other ways to do it.
The first one is to use numba's vectorize.

```py
@nb.vectorize("float64(float64)", target="parallel", nopython=True)
def numba_vectorize_cpu(a):
    return math.atan(a)


@nb.vectorize("float64(float64)", target="cuda")
def numba_vectorize_cuda(a):
    return math.atan(a)
```

Note that to use cuda option, you need to install [cudatoolkit](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/overview.html#requirements).

These are very easy to implement, yet one of the most efficient numba-based solutions.

```
numba_vectorize_cpu: 101 ms
numba_vectorize_cuda: 213 ms
```

The reason it is actually slower on GPUs is definitely because data transfer is the bottleneck.
Below you can see how long numba takes to transfer.

```py
from numba import cuda


def numba_copy_only(a):
    ac = cuda.to_device(a)
    return ac.copy_to_host()
```

```
numba_copy_only: 188 ms
```

Remember, this is more than three times longer than `numba_jit_cpu_buf` just to transfer the data.
If your data was float32, there was still a possibility, but with float64 there is no chance.

Let's try the pytorch solutions as well.

```py
import torch


class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.atan(x)


def pytorch_cpu(model, a):
    x = torch.from_numpy(a)
    return model(x).numpy()


def pytorch_cuda(model, a):
    x = torch.from_numpy(a).to("cuda")
    return model(x).cpu().numpy()


def pytorch_copy_only(a):
    x = torch.from_numpy(a).to("cuda")
    return x.cpu().numpy()
```

```
pytorch_cpu: 112 ms
pytorch_cuda: 186 ms
pytorch_copy_only: 180 ms
```

Not much difference.

It should be noted, that it is theoretically possible to make it faster by taking advantage of [DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#module-torch.utils.data) features such as prefetching and pinned memory.
However, it is not easy and you may find yourself going down the rabbit hole.
Keep in mind that with just one extra memory allocation or two writes, it will be slower than `numba_jit_cpu_buf`.

Here is the rest of benchmark code.

```py
import timeit


def baseline(a):
    return np.arctan(a)


def benchmark():
    rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
    batch = rng.random((20, 3 * 1000 * 1000), dtype=np.float64) * np.pi - np.pi / 2

    expected = baseline(batch)

    n = 100
    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: baseline(batch), number=n) / n
    print(f"baseline: {elapsed*1000:.0f} ms")

    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: single_thread_allocation(batch), number=n) / n
    print(f"single_thread_allocation: {elapsed * 1000:.0f} ms")

    buf = np.zeros_like(batch)
    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: single_thread_write(batch, buf), number=n) / n
    print(f"single_thread_write: {elapsed * 1000:.0f} ms")

    assert np.allclose(expected.ravel(), numba_jit_cpu(batch.ravel()))
    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: numba_jit_cpu(batch.ravel()), number=n) / n
    print(f"numba_jit_cpu: {elapsed * 1000:.0f} ms")

    buf = np.zeros_like(batch)
    numba_jit_cpu_buf(batch.ravel(), buf.ravel())
    assert np.allclose(expected, buf)
    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: numba_jit_cpu_buf(batch.ravel(), buf.ravel()), number=n) / n
    print(f"numba_jit_cpu_buf: {elapsed * 1000:.0f} ms")

    assert np.allclose(expected, numba_vectorize_cpu(batch))
    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: numba_vectorize_cpu(batch), number=n) / n
    print(f"numba_vectorize_cpu: {elapsed * 1000:.0f} ms")

    assert np.allclose(expected, numba_vectorize_cuda(batch))
    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: numba_vectorize_cuda(batch), number=n) / n
    print(f"numba_vectorize_cuda: {elapsed * 1000:.0f} ms")

    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: numba_copy_only(batch), number=n) / n
    print(f"numba_copy_only: {elapsed * 1000:.0f} ms")

    model = Model().eval()
    assert np.allclose(expected, pytorch_cpu(model, batch))
    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: pytorch_cpu(model, batch), number=n) / n
    print(f"pytorch_cpu: {elapsed * 1000:.0f} ms")

    model = model.to("cuda")
    assert np.allclose(expected, pytorch_cuda(model, batch))
    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: pytorch_cuda(model, batch), number=n) / n
    print(f"pytorch_cuda: {elapsed * 1000:.0f} ms")

    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: pytorch_copy_only(batch), number=n) / n
    print(f"pytorch_copy_only: {elapsed * 1000:.0f} ms")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    benchmark()
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading 720 terabytes from disk will be the bottleneck, if the only computation you do is arctan. It is better to embed the arctan into the algorithm that produces the 720 terabytes data or the one that will really use that data. Otherwise, streaming 720 terabytes just for arctan will thrash all caches of CPU, bottlenecked on SSD and consume a lot of energy. But arctan embedded on just last line of data production algorithm would evade all the negative parts above, except having to alter the existing codes.

Assuming arctan only consists of ~30 FLOPs, you'd require only 30 FLOPS per 4 bytes or 30 GFLOP/s for 4 GB/s. If you have an SSD rated at 4GB/s serial reading performance, then you only require a CPU core with 30GFLOP/s. Current processors deliver ~5x the performance for parallelized codes or ~0.5x for scalar version. Chances are second CPU core may be needed and Numba on CPU is already good for this.

Comment: I will edit my post above because the 80mil arrays are generated dynamically at runtime, they are not on disk. Because of this, I can divide the 80mil arrays up across any number of GPU jobs, e.g. 5mil rows per job and run 16 GPU jobs to finish computing all the data. I can fit 20 rows at a time (of 3mil cols) to generate a GPU batch job that fits in memory, then loop over the 5mil rows 20 at a time.

Comment: Even dividing the work up described above, it will likely take days of compute per GPU node. So I'm looking for the fastest way to do trig on large arrays. Assume I can fit the array in memory, something in the vicinity of (20,3mil) floats at a time.

Comment: If array is not really stored anywhere, then its virtual array or not array at all. Perhaps you can just re-calculate elements whenever they are accessed, instead of storing 720 TB anywhere. Sometimes this is faster if operation workload is very few.